# Help me identify the Car this wheel belongs to please (DKW)

Tags: audi, old-cars, classic, identify-this

I recently found this old DKW rim and tire in my shed and was wondering if anyone could help me identify which era  the car that this wheel belonged to was from or perhaps even identify the model of car. Unfortunately I only found the wheels and tires and no other parts. The car probably belonged to my great great grandfather but I have not found any photos of him with the car yet.

The centre to centre distance of two opposing lug holes is approximately  100mm. The lug hole diameter is 16mm. The diameter of The hole in the centre is approximately 61mm.

*The following text can be found on the tire:*

```
ENGLEBERT BALLON
4,75-5,00/17
Type A.D.
Made in Belgium
Fabrique en Belgique 
6297995
```

The (6 digit) number which is found on the tire is hard to read due to the old age of the tire so I'm not entirely sure if it is 100% correct. I've attached photos of the wheel and tire:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you also measure the distance (as close as you can) between the centerpoints of two opposing lug holes? Also, measure the hole in the center.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The centre to centre distance of two opposing lug holes is approximately  100mm. The lug hole diameter is 16mm. The diameter of The hole in the centre is approximately 61mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks 1930s in style, so a bit of hunting through the web suggests it's probably from one of the DKW 'F' series small saloons - F1 - F9 - there's several photos on Wikipedia showing those cars wearing similar looking wheels.

Others might be able to narrow it down a bit more - as Paul suggests the hub dimensions may help, but I'd suggest it's unlikely we'll be able to narrow it down to the exact model as such parts tended to be common across a range.

Comment: The centre to centre distance of two opposing lug holes is approximately  100mm. The lug hole diameter is 16mm. The diameter of The hole in the centre is approximately 61mm.